# Difference between image_transport::Subscriber AND ros::Subscriber?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the Difference between image_transport::Subscriber AND ros::Subscriber?.

Which is more efficient?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319140/difference-between-image_transport::subscriber-and-ros::subscriber?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- [`ros::Subscriber`](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html) is a generic subscriber class that can subscribe to any topic.
- [`image_transport::Subscriber`](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1Subscriber.html) is a specialized subscriber that can only subscribe to image topics, it is provided for ease of use with the `image_transport` package.

You use them for different purposes.

- Take a look at the tutorials if you want to learn how to use the `image_transport::Subscriber` http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filippo Grazioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/29827/filippo-grazioli/) on 2019-07-04**:
Is there a difference in terms of efficiency?
For instance, is image_transport::Subscriber "faster" than ros::Subscriber?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-07-04**:
None that I know, it's just for ease of use.